TLS version 1.0 in default url of AWS Rest API gateway
Rest API Gateway generates a default url and SSL/TLS server supports version 1.0 whereas custom domain name and api gateway domain name supports v1.2
We have enabled v1.2 on api gateway custom domain but still default api gateway domain supports v1.0.
